# Prove that if sets A and B are subsets of each other that A = B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a CS student that's never taken a class on set theory. The instruction I've received isn't great and I want to make sure I'm approaching this correctly since I don't feel fully comfortable with proofs yet

---

Problem: We want to prove that if two sets are subsets of each other, then these two sets are equal.

Definitions:

A is a subset of B iff ∀x (x ∈ A $\Rightarrow$ x ∈ B)

Two sets are equal iff ∀x (x ∈ A $\iff$ x ∈ B)

---

*Proof by Contradiction:*

We want to prove that A ⊆ B $\land$ B ⊆ A $\iff$ A = B

Suppose A $\neq$ B

This means ∃x such that (x ∈ A $\iff$ x ∈ B) is false

As such, one of the following two conditions must be true:

∃x ∈ A | x is not a member of B meaning A cannot be a subset of B

∃x ∈ B | x is not a member of A meaning B cannot be a subset of A

This contradicts the premise of A ⊆ B $\land$ B ⊆ A

Comment: $(P\implies Q)\wedge (Q\implies P)$ is usually how one defines $(P\iff Q)$...

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'll be honest, I don't fully know what that means or how to apply it to this problem. That just brings me to (A ⊆ B /\ B ⊆ A) => A = B and A = B => A ⊆ B /\ B ⊆ A

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. Provided below is another proof to hopefully help you understand what JMoravitz said.

---

Let A and B be any two arbitrary sets where A⊆B and B⊆A.
Using inclusion we have ∀x(x ∈ A ⇒ x ∈ B) and ∀x (x ∈ B ⇒ x ∈ A).
We can combine these two statements to get, ∀x ((x ∈ A ⇒ x ∈ B) ∧ (x ∈ B ⇒ x ∈ A)).
We now use the definition of the double implication that JMoravitz mentioned, i.e.
(P⟺Q) = (P⟹Q)∧(Q⟹P).
We finally get that ∀x (x ∈ A ⟺ x ∈ B).

Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof from an elementary intro to proofs class. Hope this helps

1. Take any $x\in A$. Since $A\subseteq B$, every element in A is in B, thus $x\in B$
2. Take any $x\notin A$. Since $B\subseteq A$, every element that's not in A is not in B, so $x\notin B$ (if $x\in B,B\subseteq A$ implies $x\in A$, a contradiction)

Since we've shown that any element that's in A is in B, and any element that's not in A is not in B, A=B.